# Filtering by Reviewed By field problems SP 2010

Tags: 2010, list-view

Good morning everyone, and thank you in advance for any help. I have taken over SharePoint for my job and I have no previous SP training. I am having an issue with views/filters. Any assistance would be appreciated.

A department posts Procedures for departmental employees to review. In the Form, there is a lookup that pulls data from a Phone Directory list of names. After an employee reviews the procedure, they edit the item and move their name from the Left column to the right column using the "add" button.

What they want is when they have reviewed the procedure and have moved their name over to the right column, marked reviewed, for that Procedure to drop off their list of procedures.[image]

The thing I am struggling with is how to pull them off. I have used syntax like this: **Reviewed By is equal to <>[Me]** and **Reviewed By is not equal to {Reviewed}** (sorry having 0 reputation only allows me for one link it looks like).

But neither of those syntax seems to work.

However, when I do use **Reviewed By "is equal to" [Me]**, it shows ZERO items, so I think I am on the right track.

I am just not sure if this is even where I look, if that second column of the Reviewed By field has it's own label? How does SP differentiate between column1 and column2?

Thanks again in advance,
Andy